# Design question: Multiple threads needing to access log files for read/write in c# application

Tags: c#, logging, thread-safety

I am having issues with multiple threads in a c# application trying to read and/or write to a log file. Occasionally an exception is thrown, and I am suspecting this is due to collisions. Is there a good way to guarantee exclusive access for each thread when it opens the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locking is probably the more suitable way here. If performance is critical, you could resort to some kind of queuing of the log messages with e.g. a `ConcurrentQueue<T>`, which should be quite optimized for concurrent read/write, together with a producer consumer pattern.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. Specially this the main concern is that the number of threads can continue to increase. The issues I am seeing are with 6 threads, but I could potentially have up to 22 threads, which would only make things worse. @SalvatorePreviti

Comment: You may have 21 threads waiting to write to the file, but how much file is being written at once? Since you're logging the file writes should be very minimal/fast.

Comment: they are. These are messages of 500 characters or less each. The delay in logging is not a big risk, it's just the collisions.

Answer (score 2):

You can fix that with locking a sync object in the logger class. Something like this would work and is what I do for my logger code.

```
private static readonly object syncObject = new object();

// .. when ready to write to a file in a method
lock(syncObject)
{
    // write to file here, 
    // no other thread is able to write to the file while this is locked
}
```

This synchronizes the file writes and guarantees that you won't have write "collisions".

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing to do is use a logging framework, such as log4net, that is thread-safe out of the box.

If for some reason you cannot use a logging framework, you will have to use one of the thread-syncing methods mentioned above and manage access yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an object to lock the file.

Write your file access code within `lock(object) { your file access code ... }` so that it will not be executed simultaneously.

Comment: Hey looks similar to my answer except you didn't specify that it needed to be static so all logger objects can reference the _same_ sync object.

Answer (score 0):

Filesystems generally have built-in locking systems, so unless your threads are all using the same `Stream` object then you should be fine. If they're *not*, set up your own lock for each file access (normally concurrent reads can be done but if you don't want to use a different stream for each one it is impossible):

```
lock(streamObject) {
    // access the file here
}
```

I would recommend you create a different stream for each access or each thread, however. If you *are* using different streams, I don't think that's your problem...

Note that this doesn't count as creating a new stream:

```
using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(theBaseStream)) {
 ...
```

because it still uses the same base `Stream` object.

Answer (score 0):

What about a thread only for logging that communicates through a concurrent queue and slim wait events?

Then you can write from multiple threads in a non-blocking way, good for multiprocessor systems.

You just enqueue a new log object or better, a struct or just a string and the thread that receive queue events can then print\write\save\manipulate the received messages in a totally asynchronous way.

You can read files from that queue with messages to that thread too (something like invokes or sendmessage).